# passing call back functions to promise.then()

Tags: javascript

when the call back functions in the myFunction gets called is it when the caller function makes a call like this  myFunciton.then ()? Can I say the first one triggers upon myFunction being resolved and second call back function is called upon failure of the myFunction?

```
 myFunciton: function() {    
     const myPromise = myService.loadData(oParams);    
     myPromise.then(() => {
          //do something
     }, () => {
          //do something else
     });
     return myPromise;   
 }
```

Comment: sorry wrong name

Answer (score 1):

Promises are a state machine with several potential states: pending(The initial state), fulfilled, and rejected.

When you create a new promise you provide a callback that accepts two parameters both functions resolve and reject respectively. resolve to enter a state of fulfilled, reject to enter a state of rejected, and if the code your promise wraps throws an exception the promise will also enter a state of rejected. Upon being either resolved or rejected your promise will store the returned value for subsequent resolutions.

Now whenever you call myPromise.then, myPromise.catch, or providing a call back function. The promise internally checks it's state.

If the promise is pending, it will queue your handlers, and when a call to reject, resolve, or an exception is thrown it will iterate through the queued handlers and call the appropriate handler(Depending on whether it was resolved or rejected).

Now if the promise is already fulfilled or rejected, the promise will call the appropriate handler asynchronously.

Let's look at your code:

```
 myFunction: function() {  
     const myPromise = myService.loadData(oParams);  
     // handlers are queued if myPromise is pending
     // function passed to then is called asynchronously if resolved
     // callback will be called asynchronously if rejected
     myPromise.then(() => {
          //do something
     }, () => {
          //do something else
     });
     return myPromise;   
 }
```

Now your question on when your callbacks will be called.

```
// This will trigger the execution of myService.loadData
// As pointed out in the comments above your callbacks will either be queued, or 
// called asynchronously.
// The value of myPromiseResult will always be a promise(pending, resolved, or    // rejected)
const myPromiseResult = myFunction();

// Here's the cool part, since promises are essentially a state machine
// every subsequent callback will yield the same result
myPromiseResult.then(() => {
    // if the callback pass to myPromise.then is called within myFunction
    // this will be called as well, and if you were passing a result
    // it would have the same result as well
}, () => {
   // if the error callback pass to myPromise within myFunction was called
   // then this will be called as well, and as mentioned above would have
   // been passed the same result as well.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

With that code, the first promise that will be resolved will be the one inside "myFunciton" function. Then, if you used something like myFunciton.then(), it will be resolved in second place.

I hope i could help you.

Comment: Should be a comment not an answer.